# Как размещается std::string в памяти

Tags: c++, строки, стек, ram

Разбираясь с устройством ОЗУ пришел к вопросу о реализации string'a. По идее это уже просто стандартная штука, но не смог найти нужной инфы. Вопрос стоит так: пусть я объявил и считал строковую переменную `s`

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
```

В какой области памяти хранится `s` (все в стеке или в стеке только указатель, а основная часть в куче), каков ее размер (всегда переопределяется как у динамического массива или выделяется сразу много места), хранятся ли там только символы в привычном однобайтном виде или есть еще какая-то информация о строке, в каком порядке хранятся байты (от младшего к старшему или наоборот).

Попробовал сам выяснить и написал следующее:

```
int main()
{
    int stack_top;
    int stack_bottom;
    string s;
    __asm {
        mov stack_top, esp
        mov stack_bottom, ebp
    }
    cin >> s;
    cout << "top = " << stack_top << endl;
    cout << "bottom = " << stack_bottom << endl;
    cout << "\n\n&s = " << &s << endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        cout << (int)&(s[i]) << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Введя 1234 в качестве строки, получил:

[image: Результат выполнения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpbx3.png)

006FF830 соответствует ‭7338032‬ байту, в связи с чем не понятно, на что идут 4 первых байта.
Ну и исходя из листинга, получается, что все хранится в стеке, но тогда вопрос как реализовано выделение памяти под новые символы.

(в ответах ссылки на источники приветствуются)

Comment: Обычно содержимое в куче, но у вас сработала SSO (short string optimization).

Comment: *"По идее это уже просто стандартная штука, но не смог найти нужной инфы."* Стандартный - интерфейс и некоторые ограничения, но не реализация. А вообще-то надо просто покопаться в `<string>`...

Comment: Прочитав про SSO узнал много интересного, действительно, обычно все хранится в куче, но при длине строки не достигающей 16 символов, строка хранится в стеке, а когда появляется 16 символ, память выделяется в куче и строка переносится туда. Что касается первых 4 байт, выяснил, что там хранится адрес какого-то байта в куче, но это увы не тот байт, с которого начинается строка при ее длине в 16+ символов. что это за адрес все еще не понятно..

Comment: Так пройдитесь по реализации `cin >> s;` построчно в отладчике и поглядите, что и как там заполняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам объект `s` хранится в стеке, но в классе `std::basic_string` должен быть доступ к внутреннему символьному массиву, который, в силу динамического размера строки, тоже является динамическим, т.е. хранится в куче. Однако в случае малых размеров строки **может** выполняться *short string optimization*, тогда и массив будет выделен на стеке.

Аналогичный вопрос на английском стеке https://stackoverflow.com/q/42049778.